# GTK-error while running a pyplot-application

Tags: pantheon-files, programming, gtk

When I try to run a python application which uses a pyplot-window, I get a warning in the command line:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
```

How can I fix it, and what causes it?

Comment: Hi arc_lupus, the below answer only explains the reason for the error. But how did you overcome the issue?

Comment: @learner: Ignored it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pantheon Files (the default file manager) contains a custom GTK+ module called `pantheon-filechooser-module`.

It's shipped on up-to-date systems, but it's not activated yet (currently, the default GTK+ file chooser dialog is still in use). That's most likely the reason it fails to load. Additionally, it *might* fail because it is a GTK+2 application.

On the other hand, it might be possible you removed Pantheon files. If that's the case, it might be the (other) reason the module fails to load, because it's not installed on your system.

Comment: After `pantheon-files` is running multiple times in htop, I assume that I did not uninstall it. How can I activate the module?

Comment: You actually don't need to activate it, afaik it's still being tested - and the failed loading does not break your app. Is your app GTK+2 by any chance?

Comment: matplotlib/pyplot could be GTK+2, yes.

Comment: Looking through some information on the internet, it is indeed GTK+2 - As the filechooser-module is a GTK+3 module, it fails upon loading. Nothing to worry about! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1."You will always see this message with non-gtk3 apps. It's harmless and you can ignore it."

OR

2.`sudo rm /etc/profile.d/pantheon-filechooser-module.sh`

Comment: Don't delete it , rename it to `pantheon-filechooser-module.sh.old`